# Load asp:Chart from a different server to my div

Tags: jquery, cross-domain

I have a web page in Server1 which displays a chart using asp:Chart. My app is deployed in Server2 and tries to load my div as below

```
$("#div").load("http://server1/charts", function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "error") {            
            alert("Error: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }
    });
```

Unfortunately, I am getting an error as `Error: 0 No Transport`
Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Have you set [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) headers on server1?

Comment: @Musa, Thanks for your helps. I added `Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` in the page load event. But it did not help

Answer (score 1):

to enable cross domain calls, you can try

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
```

if this doesn't works you can go through :
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Jul/04/JSONP-for-crosssite-Callbacks
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON
http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/

you can follow any of these

Comment: Thanks for your helps. I added `Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` in the page load event. But it did not help

Comment: In the mentioned url it is given how to do cross domain callback, did you try them?